# How to view a signed envelope document via DocuSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I have successfully used the CreateEnvelope API method to send envelope (with multiple documents) to the client for signing. I have also successfully wired up the callback URL using the eventNotification object as explained in this question:

[How can I setup a web hook to check on DocuSign Envelope status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244961/how-can-i-setup-a-web-hook-to-check-on-docusign-envelope-status)

What I want to do now is to allow my users to view/download the envelope documents which were signed. How can I accomplish this via DocuSign API? Is there a URL that I can target to view the documents providing I have the accountId, envelopeId and documentId?

Comment: Do you want just the PDF bytes themselves or an actual web view hosted by DocuSign which includes all the documents in the envelope?

Comment: @LuisScott Ideally I think that I would have a list of documents in the envelope and those that were signed would be a link that when clicked would either open the document for viewing in the browser or allow for document download...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of embedded vs remote signing, you can use the REST API to download a complete PDF of all the documents in the envelope. Documentation available: https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20Envelope%20Documents%20and%20Certificate.htm?Highlight=pdf

IF you are doing embedded signing today, if you make the same API call used to start an embedded signing experience for an envelope which is already completed, DocuSign will return a URL which displays the documents in read only mode. There is an option to download the PDF's through this view as well.

Answer (score 0):

Luis's answer is correct and it pointed me in the right direction. I want to explain what I did to help anyone else who might be facing the same problem.

I am using the Docusign's esigning api available here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=docusign

This way I don't have to deal with making my own API requests. That being said the package exposes the class EnvelopesApi which has a method called CreateConsoleView/CreateConsoleViewAsync. This method returns a ViewUrl object instance which contains the url you need to redirect to in order to open the envelope in the docusign console view. Assuming you are writing a .NET MVC app:

```
public ActionResult View(string envelopeId) {
    var api = new EnvelopesApi();
    var response = api.CreateConsoleView(yourAccountId, new ConsoleViewRequest { EnvelopeId = yourEnvelopeId });
    return Redirect(response.Url);
}
```