# Sample require for message 5a(once signing ceremony finished)

Tags: docusignapi

I think, once we send message 1a envelop to docusign. And after signing ceremony completed, next step to receive message 5a, this message our application receive. As per understanding, we got message and signed documents.

Can please provide sample message which we receive, so that we can design our API to support this.?

Please note - we are using rest API. so we prefer to have JSON based.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your question. And please upvote any answers that you find helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're asking about the notification messages sent to clients via the DocuSign webhook system, **Connect**.

Here's an [example notification message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37244961/how-can-i-setup-a-web-hook-to-check-on-docusign-envelope-status/37270688#37270688). A JSON message format is not yet available, it is planned for this Autumn.

### Added

(Based on the OP's comment...)

There are two ways for your application to learn the status of an envelope:

1. Use a webhook. DocuSign will call your application when the envelope is complete. The DocuSign webhook system is called "Connect."
2. Poll DocuSign. You can poll DocuSign, asking about the status of an envelope no more frequently than once every 15 minutes.

Comment: Something like this, but this is not exactly. Here I want to say, let me explain with example. For example - we sent envelop with 5 entities to do electronic sign through your platform on some set of PDF document. Once all signer  has completed their electronic signature on PDF documents then we expect some notification on our API and our API expect this envelop with 5 entities details with all signed PDF documents. We will maintain all signed documents at our end and update record of envelop in our system. Hope you understand my points.

Comment: @ManojSharma -- See the added information in my answer. If you have further questions, please open a new question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks @Larry K -- Actually this is not any new question. I try to explore to get my answer. Let me check link which I got https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect